# How do I setup a Rails association where one model belongs to two instances of another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models ObjectA and ObjectB. ObjectB has two columns, a_1_id and a_2_id, which are both foreign keys to ObjectA. ObjectB belongs to each of these foreign ObjectA objects.

```
class ObjectA < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :player_1, :player_2, :subject, :turn

  belongs_to :player_1, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :player_2, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :object_b, dependent: :destroy, :finder_sql => "SELECT * FROM object_bs where (a_1_id = #{id} or a_2_id = #{id})" 
end

class ObjectB < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :a_1_id, :a_2_id

  belongs_to :a_1_id, :class_name => "ObjectA"
  belongs_to :a_2_id, :class_name => "ObjectA"
end
```

Is this the best way to setup the association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [:foreign_key](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) option:

```
belongs_to :player_1, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'player1_id'
belongs_to :player_2, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'player2_id'
#...
belongs_to :a_1_id, :class_name => "ObjectA", :foreign_key => 'a_1_id'
belongs_to :a_2_id, :class_name => "ObjectA", :foreign_key => 'a_2_id'
```

Comment: I thought Rails could determine that by simply appending _id to the given name. Is that not the case?

Comment: When you declare `belongs_to :player_1`, it assumes there's a Player1 class and looks for the key 'player1_id'. When you specify `:class_name => 'User'`, it will look for key 'user_id'.

Comment: If I add the foreign key, I still receive the following error when trying to delete an instance of ObjectA: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: object_bs.object_a_id: SELECT "object_bs".* FROM "object_bs"  WHERE "object_bs"."object_a_id" = 4

Comment: That's due to `has_many :object_b, dependent: :destroy` specify the foreign_key there as well.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help! One more clarification if you have time. ObjectB belongs has two different foreign keys for ObjectA. What would I specify for the foreign_key after the has_many in that case?

Comment: ah yes... I believe you'd have to declare 2 `has_many`'s, just like the `belongs_to`'s. Give them different names.